# How to update multiple primary key with foreach looping?

Tags: php

I want to update PIC_ID in multiple primary keys.
This is my code :

```
//Input from checkbox
<input type="checkbox" name="PSID[]" value="<?php echo $rows['PSID']; ?>" size="5" readonly="readonly"/>

<input type="hidden" name="surveyor" value="<?php echo $_GET['idsurveyor']; ?>" />


//PSID is a primary key

$pic=$_POST['surveyor'];
foreach ($_POST['PSID'] as $key => $value) {

    $value; 
    $pic;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE surveyor SET PIC_ID='$pic' WHERE PSID='$value'");    
    $stmt->execute() ;
    } //foreach
```

// and only one incoming data into a table

Comment: If you have setup indizes and a relation between your tables you could simply setup an "ON UPDATE CASCADE" event, then you only need to update the top table and all referenced values will auto update.

Comment: That query of yours is a mockery of Prepared Statements :)

Comment: @up: haha yeah it is indeed, SQL injections welcome